# Changing a string to variable

Tags: python

I'm working with Python 2.6 here.
Perhaps my title is misleading. So I will explain here. I tried my best to search for a solution, but since I'm rather new I have no clue *what* to search.

Essentially, I'm getting an input string value from the user, and I wish to do the following:

Let's say

```
x=['reg1','reg2','reg3']
```

I want to write:

```
for reg in x:
    display_value.reg
```

Such that python reads the following for every iteration:

```
display_value.regX
```

and NOT:

```
display_value.'regX'
```

Comment: wait... changing a string to a variable? What does that make a string?
anyway, your question refers to using `getattr()`. You want `getattr(display_value, reg)`

Comment: What advantage do you think this will offer over storing `reg` as a list or a dictionary which could be iterated over directly?  Almost always when you're using more than one integer suffix in a variable name you've taken a wrong step.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I should've been searching for. As I said, I had little idea as to *what* I should search. Thank you very much for this

Comment: Most likely, you want to make `display_value` a dictionary, and not faff around with `getattr()`.

Comment: @crow Like I said, I didn't know how to ask the question. Apologies. getattr is what I was looking for.

Comment: @DSM what do you mean by iterating over directly? I understand lists and dictionaries

Comment: not to be harsh, but if you don't know what to ask, it's likely you're not really understanding what you're asking. I think a more appropriate title would be "extracting a string variable from a class"

Comment: @user3757519: I mean that if you had (effectively) `display_value.reg = [1,2,3]`, you could do `for x in display_value.reg`, etc.  Or similarly if it were a dictionary.

Comment: I plus one'd because I think this sort of question is needed, and it will prevent future duplicates from askers thinking along the same lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `getattr`:

```
x=['reg1','reg2','reg3']

for attr in x:                   
    getattr(display_value, attr) # same as display_value.attr, attr not a string.
```

You may find it useful to provide a default value in case your object doesn't have the attr:

```
foo = getattr(obj, attr, 'default value') # typically better to use None.
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Aaron Hall's solution works, I'd say that "what you **really** want is to use a `dict`, not an object instance".

Although it's possible to introspect almost everything in Python, and thus you can use an object as a `dict` in Python, full-blown objects carry around some extra baggage and complexity that makes them ill-suited for the simple case of a mapping (e.g. `key1 => value1, key2 => value2`).

A `dict` is the appropriate container type for this:

```
keys = ['reg1','reg2','reg3']
display_value = dict( map(None, keys, ()) )

for key in keys:
    # do something with the value of display_value[key]
```